# Search engine for English idioms?

Tags: discussion, resources

I am looking for a resources which can provide related English idioms/phrases. For instance, if I were looking up 'to help out', I would find 'to pitch in', etc. Does any such resources exist online (or offline)?

Comment: [BookAuthority.org](https://bookauthority.org/books/best-english-idioms-books) has [at No 20] '_The Thesaurus of English Idioms_ by George L Nagy is the first serious attempt [2006] in the English language to construct **a dictionary of synonymous phrases**. The current collection contains: 21,500 entries, including 12,500 core idioms; 9,000 **cross-references** with complete explanatory notes; 22,000 example sentences; 100,000 synonymous phrases explaining the idioms.' (amended slightly). But an 'ELU Meta' question.

Comment: A dictionary will contain most such idioms. Regional ones or newer slang will require a more specialized resource (eg DARE), but for 99% of fixed phrases you will encounter, a dictionary will suffice.

Comment: @danBron A dictionary will explain the idiom; it won't necessarily suggest synonymous or associated phrases